# TinyMCE - How to add a button that wraps selected text with a tag

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm currently using TinyMCE and would like to add a custom button that works as follows:

1. User highlights text in the text-editior
2. User clicks the custom button X
3. The text (dog walking) is wrapped with a tag (dog walking)

Any ideas on if this can be done? I've figured out how to make a custom button inject text, but not wrap text... Here is the current code:

```
// Add a custom button
ed.addButton('mybutton', {
    title : 'My button',
    'class' : 'MyCoolBtn',
    image : 'MyCoolBtn.png',
    onclick : function() {
        // Add you own code to execute something on click
        ed.focus();
        ed.selection.setContent('<strong>Hello world!</strong>');
    }
});
```

---

thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
ed.addButton('mybutton', {
  title: 'My button', 
  class: 'MyCoolBtn', 
  image: 'MyCoolBtn.png', 
  onclick: function() { 
    // Add your own code to execute something on click 
    ed.focus();
    ed.selection.setContent('<tag>' + ed.selection.getContent() + '</tag>');
  }
});
```

Comment: One question @Warrior, why do you need the `ed.focus();`? Thanks

Comment: According to the TinyMCE API Documentation at http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.focus the purpose of this call is to:

"set this editor as the activeEditor in the tinymce collection. it will also place DOM focus inside the editor."

Answer (score 13):

A better way to achieve this is to (1) perform a quick check to make sure the selection isn't empty, then (2) use the `execCommand()` method.

Using `execCommand()` means the action will be available to undo. @Warrior's answer uses `setContent()` which will not be undoable.

```
ed.addButton('mybutton', {
  title: 'My button', 
  class: 'MyCoolBtn', 
  image: 'MyCoolBtn.png', 
  onclick: function() { 
    ed.focus();
    var text = ed.selection.getContent({'format': 'html'});
    if(text && text.length > 0) {
      ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<tag>'+text+'</tag>');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Except it should be `mceReplaceContent`. Any ideas on how to select it afterwards?

Comment: How can you only add the tag if the selection is not already surrounded by the tag?