# TinyMCE code highlighter select code to apply code highlight

Tags: tinymce

I am looking for a tinymce code highlighting plugin that is easy for users to use.I want the users to highlight the code to code highlight and with a click of a button,the code is highlighted,like how stackoverflow does it,without resulting to

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry just a little confused?

Are you wanting search results to be highlighted when a user goes to a page from a search if so this is not TinyMCE it's Server side when you get the text from the database do a search and replace on the text with a background coloured span

E.G [PHP]

```
// with this example i'm assuming that you link to the post from search is in a get variable called searchTerm if you url_encode it you need to url_decode it.
$highlight = $_GET['searchTerm']; // section
$text = "this is a section of text"
$text = str_replace($highlight, "<span style='background-color:#666;'>$highlight</span>");
echo $text
```

If not can you clarify what you looking for?

Comment: The syntax highlighter i have for tinymce requires a user to remember the brush to use,for instance:<pre class="brush: js;">
function helloSyntaxHighlighter()
{
 return "hi!";
}
</pre>

</html>
I want my user to just highlight the code they have written,and with a click of a button,the text highlighted is given the code coloring.

Comment: SOLVED:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878418/tinymce-how-to-add-a-button-that-wraps-selected-text-with-a-tag